# Using @computed for array.length in mobx?

Tags: javascript, mobx

In mobx, when using `observable.array()` does it make sense to calculate `.length` in a `@computed` property, or it is already cached somehow internally?

Generally what kind of properties does it make sense to cache in a `@computed`? Should I use it for everything? Can it possibly lead to unneeded recalculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length property of an observable array is [**defined as follows**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/types/observablearray.ts#L549):

```
Object.defineProperty(ObservableArray.prototype, "length", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    get: function(): number {
        return this.$mobx.getArrayLength()
    },
    set: function(newLength: number) {
        this.$mobx.setArrayLength(newLength)
    }
})
```

All `this.$mobx.getArrayLength` does [**is the following**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/types/observablearray.ts#L176):

```
getArrayLength(): number {
    this.atom.reportObserved()
    return this.values.length
}
```

The benefit you will get from caching it in a `@computed` will be slim to none.

It's a good practice to cache computations that you use often. I personally use it for everything from `@computed fullName() { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; }`, to e.g. a cached [**supercluster**](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster). It's more a question of taste, unless you are dealing with heavier computations, when it becomes very useful.